# offline map using big planet sqlite database

Tags: android, google-maps, offline

I am new in android development . I want to develop offline google map.
I use Mobile Atlas Creator and create **BigPlanet_maps.sqlitedb.** 
But how can I use this database in android development? How can I display offline map using       BigPlanet_maps.sqlitedb? Is there another way to display offline google map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both BigPlanet and Osmdroid.ZIP are atlas output formats for MOBAC. If you create the atlas in the Osmdroid.ZIP format and use the [Osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) jar in your application, then you can have offline capability.

Osmdroid is very similar to Google Maps in terms of functionality. All you need do is place the created zip file in the Osmdroid folder on your phone. Osmdroid looks for a specific tile in the zip file before trying to go online for it. I use it all the time in an app I wrote for my phone. I have the area near me in a zip file on the phone and it saves data charges.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know You cannot do this with google map ([Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/maps-api-signup)). Take a look at [OSM](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) !